# React - is the following true about how html tags' attribute values change when a component is reexecuted?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Can I verify my observation (based on the code below)?:

1. Class values of an element added in the html markup of a component don't neccessarily 'persist' - when the component is re-executed (perhaps as the result of a change in state), the class value from the last execution can disappear.
2. However, class values written via vanilla JS persist.
3. I'm always looking for best practices in code to avoid problems down the line. Is this code a reasonable way to add a class to a tag in React?

**sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-moon-epmmu?file=/src/styles.css:59-126

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let [color, setColor] = useState(false);

  function updateColor() {
    if (color) {
      setColor("");
    } else {
      setColor("red");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector(`div`).classList.add(`green-text`);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={color ? "red" : null} onClick={updateColor}>
        Click to add/remove red class
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green-text {
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to try out the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library to inject class attribute value dynamically. It's a very elegant library which helps avoid complicated code pertaining to css updates, when the codebase gets bigger.

I have tweaked your example, including some naming changes, removing unwanted code and added `classnames`. Also you can pass in any other class names from other components as such, and render it dynamically too. This is how you'd do it:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import classnames from "classnames"

export default function App(props) {
  const [hasRed, setHasRed] = useState(false);

  return (
      <div className={classnames(
          ["green-text", props.otherClassNamesIfAny],
          {
            "red": hasRed,
          }
        )} 
        onClick={setHasRed(!hasRed)}
      >
        Click to add/remove red class
      </div>
   );
};
```